# Running rsnapshot backup in a Linux virtual machine?

Tags: linux, backup, virtualization, rsync, rsnapshot

I have a remote Linux server machine that I wanted to mirror backup now and then. Since I am a Windows user, I installed Linux virtual machine on my Windows and I am now using rsnapshot to do the backup. So, rsnapshot takes data from remote linux server and backs them up into local linux virtual machine.

Is this backup inside a virtual machine safe and good thing to do?

Should I maybe install Linux normaly on a different drive and use dual boot and backup there instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you would store it on that computer anyway, it pretty much doesn't matter.

In general a better place to store backups is on more inactive storage places. (Activity on the drive makes write errors more likely)